# Filter column for substring and return max of adjacent cells -- Excel 2013 (no macros)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to obtain the max call time that was on each day, the average of all the calls that day, and any calls that exceeded 20 seconds.

Due to the security policies at work I am limited to the formulas provided by excel, I can't use macros or VB (otherwise I would just write something suitable). I don't have much experience with excel, so I apologize if this is a simple one. I have tried to find ways to search and return a subarray that I could easily manipulate, but it seems the only way to do that is with macros. Currently I think I can use `VLOOKUP`, but I don't really understand enough about it know if I can use this with another function.

Essentially, if there is a formula or a combination of formulas that I can use that will allow me to collect all data from column B that shares the same values in column A, I could nest that in the formulas I need to calculate the data.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Instead of "Fri" or "Thu" you'll need to use the actual date `5/19/2017`.  Then you can use `=MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$100=D4)*$B$2:$B$100,))` for the max length, `=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$100,D4,$B$2:$B$100)` for the average, and `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$100,D4,$B$2:$B$100,">00:00:20")` for the count of calls > 20 seconds

Comment: Alternately, you could probably do this with a pivot table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a pivot table in just a few clicks.

First, turn the source data into an Excel Table object, by selecting one cell in the table and then using **Insert > Table** or **Ctrl-T**. Add a helper column for the calls over 20 seconds. Let the column be "long calls" and the formula

```
=IF([@Duration]>TIME(0,0,20),1,0)
```

Then, with a cell of the Excel Table selected, click **Insert > Pivot Table**. (The pivot table is now linked to the Excel Table object and when more data is added you can refresh the pivot table without having to change the definition of the source data.)

Drag the *Day* field into the rows area and the *Duration* field into the Values area. Right-click any of the value results in the pivot table, and in the **Value Field Settings** dialog select **Max**. Then click on **Number Format** button and set the custom number format of **hh:mm:ss**. Confirm all dialogs.

If you want to format the date, right click any of the visible dates in the Pivot table, select **Field Settings**, click **Number Format** and then set the custom format **ddd**.

Drag the duration field into the values area again and set its calculation method to Average.

Drag the "long calls" field into the values area.

Hide the Grand Totals via the Pivot Table tools Design ribbon command.

Now you can add more data to the table in columns A to B, right click the pivot table and select refresh.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this has help tremendously! I used a few of the tricks you provided to make a few more columns.